# Django home page doesnt display

Tags: django, python-3.x

I run the following tutorial [Django Tutorial for Beginners - 2 - Creating a Project](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CHjXtRrhqxc&index=2&list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGBlmzzFcLgDhKTTfNLfX1IK)

when I run the code bellow from urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include('music.urls')),
]
```

It display the music page even that I am at http://localhost:8000/
When I remove the line

```
 url(r'^', include('music.urls')),
```

My music.py file

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from music import views


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', views.index, name="index"),
]
```

Then it goes to the home page as expected

Why does it happen? Shouldn't it go to the first line that fites?
I run django version 1.10.5

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a `music` app?

Comment: Yes, it goes to that url if I add /music

Comment: Could you include your `music/urls.py` file?

Comment: I Added it to the post  Evans Murithi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are at `localhost:8000/` it goes to the music page since the url matches the pattern defined in your urls. In your root urls.py you can make the url to music explicit by doing `url(r'^music/', include('music.urls')),`. This way, you will go to music page by hitting the endpoint `localhost:8000/music/`.

To go to the home page, add a urlpattern that matches your home page url in your root urls.py for example:

```
url(r'^/$', views.home, name='home'),
```

Comment: Itried that and I get-->


Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/
Using the URLconf defined in website.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^admin/
^music/
The current URL, , didn't match any of these.


And shouldnt it go to the first url that matches?

Comment: I dont have views.home. I am folowing the tutorial.
And why when I use only the first url  "url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls)," it finds the home page and woeks OK, but when I add another url it doesnt fin it?

Comment: What's your home page url?

Comment: I have the defual django home page- "It worked!
Congratulations on your first Django-powered page." But when I add the " url(r'^music/', include('music.urls'))," to the urls.py It doesnt get there an I get page not found

Comment: The Django's welcome page is only shown when you do not have apps in your project. Once you create an app, you'll have to map your home page url to a view

Comment: Its very strange the tutorial looks as serious one, and it works there fine, @ Evans Murithi, I will try to create an hone page (Not sure I know how)

Comment: thank it works, thats was a very helpull information that I miss out  @Evans Murithi